# Array vs enum duplication for assigning and listing post tags

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular and TypeScript, how can I create an array of tags that can be iterated over in an html file and can be accessed via an enum in a ts file?

What I am currently doing:

```
// used in my ts file for assigning tags to posts
enum EPostTags {
    tech        = 'Tech News',
    sport       = 'Sport News',
    culture     = 'Culture News',
}

// used in my html file for listing all tags for the filter function
public postTags = [
    'Tech News',
    'Sport News',
    'Culture News',
];

// all my posts including tags
public posts = [
    {
        title: "The world's most interesting post",
        tags: [ EPostTags.tech, ] // so that I get errors in VSCode if I misspell the tag
    },
]
```

HTML

```
Filter by: 
<span *ngFor="let tag of postTags" (click)="filterPostsByTag(tag)">
    {{ tag }}
</span>
```

**Is there any way to use one instead of two definitions for the tags array/enum?**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to access a list in your component, you can access a function which returns an `Array<EPostTags>`:

```
export class AppComponent {

  public getList(): Array<EPostTags>{
    let arr: Array<EPostTags> = [];
    for (let e in EPostTags){
       // Get the designated string values as defined in the enum.
       arr.push(EPostTags[`${e}`]);
    }

    return arr;
  }

  // all my posts including tags
  public posts = [
    {
      title: "The world's most interesting post",
      tags: [EPostTags.tech,] // so that I get errors in VSCode if I misspell the tag
    },
  ]

}
```

HTML:

```
<span *ngFor="let tag of getList()" (click)="filterPostsByTag(tag)">
    {{ tag }}<br>
</span>
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4hde6h

Comment: Great, thank you! With this solution, is it possible to highlight the currently selected tag via css?

Comment: @Ben I updated my stackblitz link which has an example. Probably a better way to do this - but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the enum string values:

```
public postTags = Object.values(EPostTags) as EPostTags[];
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nbelfd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: Only downside to this is that it returns `any[]` and doesn't implicitly assign the correct `EPostTags type`

Comment: @Zze - Thanks for the comment. I added the explicit cast.